# how can I make middlware to control the no one go to page without id ln Laravel 7 project

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I have LMS project and and have 3 role `admin`, `teacher`, `student`
I can't make middleware to control no one access to admin or teacher or student except

It is a Laravel 7 project.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to achieve, and why can't you make that?

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want to ensure, that everyone is properly authenticated and logged in.

In you routes file you should run all routes where only authenticated user should have access through the `auth` middlware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    // more routes
});
```

To specify where the user should be redirected to you can open the middleware at [`app/Http/Middlware/Authentication.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L7) and check the method

```php
protected function redirectTo($request)
```

Comment: I want created middelware from zero

Comment: @MazenKhalid You can read about writing your own middleware in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have role column in your users table.

Middleware code should be:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()-> role === 'ADMIN') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return back();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will be useful & don't forget to read Laravel documentation of the same, this will improve your skills.

Same way you can create middleware for other roles also.